# rqt_graph not working anymore on galactic

Tags: ros2, rqt, rqt-graph, rqt-gui, ros-galactic

I had this problem for a while now, and wasn't able to solve it despite all attempts, `rqt_graph` used to work just fine, but all the sudden (probably after i installed something or updated something) started giving me this Error:

```
anassq@anassq-ThinkPad:~$ rqt_graph
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/galactic/bin/rqt_graph", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('rqt-graph==1.2.2', 'console_scripts', 'rqt_graph')()
  File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rqt_graph/main.py", line 9, in main
    sys.exit(Main().main(sys.argv, standalone='rqt_graph.ros_graph.RosGraph'))
  File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rqt_gui/main.py", line 57, in main
    return super(
  File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qt_gui/main.py", line 408, in main
    from python_qt_binding import QT_BINDING
  File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/python_qt_binding/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from python_qt_binding.binding_helper import loadUi  # noqa: F401
  File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 277, in <module>
    _select_qt_binding(
  File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 108, in _select_qt_binding
    QT_BINDING_VERSION = binding_loader(required_modules, optional_modules)
  File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 155, in _load_pyqt
    _named_optional_import('PyQt5.%s' % module_name)
  File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 142, in _named_optional_import
    _named_import(name)
  File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 133, in _named_import
    module = builtins.__import__(name)
ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name
```

I tried everything i can find, setting the `pyQt` by `sudo pip3 install pyqt5==5.15.5`
didn't work removing and reinstalling package didn't work either.

I hope someone here ran to a simular problem and found a solution, or can provide me with some suggestions.

Thanks for the read!

Comment: Hello Ravi, 
thank you so much ! It Worked. Now i know which version i need, in order to use rqt.

Comment: Glad it worked. I have moved my comment to the answer section. To mark the answer below as solved, please "upvote" and click the gray "check-mark" icon located on the left side of this answer. Once selected, the icon will turn green to confirm your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

Please install `PyQt v5.10.1` using the following command:

```
pip install PyQt5==5.10.1
```

Source: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55794141)